# Modular Classes with Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to create a class to spawn some new objects on my screen. I'm following [this tutorial](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/29/tutorial-modular-classes-in-corona/)

My goal was to do something link this:

```
local box = box.new( "First", 0, 62 ) -- Spawn a Box on the Screen on X = 0, Y = 62
```

This is my class:

```
 box.lua

local box = {}
local box_mt = {__index = box } -- metatable 

function box.new (nome, x, y)
    local newbox = {
        local nome = display.newImageRect( "images/box.png", 210, 70 )
         newbox.x = x
         newbox.y = y
     }
     return setmetatable( newbox, box_mt )
}
end
```

so far just by doing a `require ("box")` on the level1.lua my game is crashing

```
This is the error
Failed to parse error message: error loading module 'level1' from file '/Users/mc309bza/Desktop/Corona/Platform/level1.lua':
    /Users/mc309bza/Desktop/Corona/Platform/level1.lua:28: syntax error near 'function'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Also `local nome =` is a syntax error. There are no local table fields.

Answer (score 0):

The closing bracket of table is at wrong place. Use:

```
local newbox = {}
local nome = display.newImageRect( "images/box.png", 210, 70 )
newbox.x = x
newbox.y = y
```

Don't forget to remove the close `}` you have after newbox. However, if your intent is to make the creation of boxes automated, you should use a function instead, since display.newImageRect is already a class. Use a function:

```
function myNewBox(x, y)
    local nome = display.newImageRect( "images/box.png", 210, 70 )
    nome.x = x
    nome.y = y
    ... other nome settings ...
    return nome
end
```